# Plenty of Uncaught (in promise) DOMException errors in simple Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, service-worker, domexception

I'm developing simple Vue.js application as a learning project using Vue.js, Quasar and Vuex. For some unknown (to me) reason I'm getting lots of `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` errors. The application works just fine, but those red errors don't seem right. How can I debug and fix these?

While refreshing website, errors show up in console right away. I think it's even before app itself is fully loaded:

[image: Console screenshot]

Each error takes form of:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException    service-worker.js:1

Promise.then (async)
(anonymous)         @ workbox-strategies.dev.js:681
step                @ workbox-core.dev.js:14
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:25
Promise.then (async)
step                @ workbox-core.dev.js:24
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:32
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:11
_getNetworkPromise  @ workbox-strategies.dev.js:691
(anonymous)         @ workbox-strategies.dev.js:554
step                @ workbox-core.dev.js:14
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:32
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:11
makeRequest         @ workbox-strategies.dev.js:578
(anonymous)         @ workbox-strategies.dev.js:504
step                @ workbox-core.dev.js:14
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:32
(anonymous)         @ workbox-core.dev.js:11
handle              @ workbox-strategies.dev.js:508
handleRequest       @ workbox-routing.dev.js:365
(anonymous)         @ workbox-routing.dev.js:835
```

Clearing cache and hard reloading site doesn't work.

I am starting the app via `npm run dev` script.

Whole code is available on [BitBucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/Xkonti/hourslog/src)

Comment: You can't ask us to debug your whole app... Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Open your `inspector` (f12 or command + option + i)`, go to the application cache, click 'Clear Cache'` and clear everything. Your service worker is broken. You probably had something installed on this domain before.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That helped! I went to `Service Workers` in `Application` tab and clicked `Unregister` on one available. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ohgodwhy suggested, the source of the problem was some old service worker installed on my domain (in this case simply `localhost`). The idea is to remove it.

To remove service worker in Chrome browser:

1. Open developer tools in your browser (`F12` or `command + option + i`)
2. Head to `Application` tab
3. Go to `Service Workers` section
4. Click `Unregister` on service worker that could be broken